# Как получить первый элемент в сете (Set) по индексу?

Tags: javascript, set

У меня имеется сет:

```
var set = new Set([10, 20, 30, 40, 50]);
```

Как получить его значение по нулевому индексу?

В массиве я могу сделать так:

```
var num = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]; 
console.log(num[0]);
```

но не понимаю как это сделать в сете.

Comment: Плохо представляю, зачем это может понадобиться, но как вариант: `[...set][0]`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскольку у объектов [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) отсутствует метод [get()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get) как, например, у структур данных [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), то Ваш вопрос действительно интересный.

У сетов определен [протокол перебора](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols), а их "ключи" равны значениям:

```
const numbers = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]

const set = new Set(numbers)        

const isEqual = set.keys === set.values
console.log(isEqual)
// true
```

поэтому мы можем перебрать их значения, полученные с помощи методов [keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/keys) или [values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/values).

Что бы получить первое значение сета (аналогичное индексу 0):

```
const setValues = set.values()
console.log(setValues)
// [Set Iterator] { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 }

const result = setValues.next().value
console.log(result)
// 10

// или в одну строку 
// set.values().next().value
```

Что бы получить значение по нужному "индексу":

```
const getValueByIndex = (set, index) => {
    let ind = 0
    let res

    for (let value of set) {
        if (ind === index) {
            res = value
            break
        }
        ind++
    }
    return res
}

const result = getValueByIndex(set, 3)
console.log(result)
// 40
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно преобразовать объект Set в массив с помощью метода Array.from(), и уже из полученного массива получить первый элемент

```
    const set = new Set([10, 20, 30, 40, 50]);

    console.log(Array.from(set)[0]); // 10


    // или более развернуто
    const arrFromSet = Array.from(set);

    console.log(arrFromSet) // [ 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 ]

    console.log(arrFromSet[0]) // 10
```

Answer (score -1):

> set.stream().findfirst().get()

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]